# ASP.NET Web API Post method error

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I create API project using ASP.NET Web API.

and add Product class to models.

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

and ad ProductsController class to Controllers
.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> getProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        List<Product> productsInCategory = new List<Product>();

        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            if (p.category.Equals(category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                productsInCategory.Add(p);
        }

        return productsInCategory;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public void PostByProducts(string name)
    {

        int newId = 0;
        //if (products.Count > 0)
        //    newId = products[products.Count - 1].id + 1;

        //products.Add(new Product { id = newId, name = name, category = category, price = price });

    }
```

and I call post method using python requests.

```
import requests 
payload = {'name':'t1'} 
r = requests.post("http://localhost:59386/api/products",  data=payload)
print r.text
```

But, Get is well. Post not well.

I mark breakpoint in PostByProducts memthod and call request.

but don't stop breakpoint.

Comment: May be http://localhost:59386/api/products/PostByProducts ?

Comment: Check your WebApiConfig, or better share it for us.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Using Model class for POST Method parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostByProducts(Product p)
{
    products.Add(p); 
}
```

**or Use only one parameter :**

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostByProducts([FromBody] name)
{
    //any codes
}
```

and call in this case:

```
// name will be null.
$.post('api/product', { name:tom });

// name will be not null. 
$.post('api/values', "=" + value);
```

refer above line for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

WebApiConfig below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        ); 
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```